# How to add subdomain to Magento?

Tags: magento

I need to create geo subdomain for one city (for example shop.com & london.shop.com). I want the **same store**. But also I want to have different pages like:
london.shop.com/contacts & shop.com/contacts.
I use magento 1.9.2.1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad. To make it better please list the steps that you have taken to solve your problem and how your solution did not work for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create multiple websites and store for different domain.create one folder on root and put index.php and .htaccess file and change in index.php store name or website name at last.

Please refer below link

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/